# OIDC - Validating JWT's to avoid tampering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I'm using ASP.NET Core v2's `AddOpenIdConnect` authentication extension method to easily establish an OIDC with an Azure AD provider.

Here's a friendly example of what I'm doing currently, in the Startup.cs class.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // Setup default schemes...
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("OpenIdConnect-Scheme", "Azure AD", options =>
    {
        const string clientId = "myClientId";
        const string instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        const string tenantId = "myTenantId";

        options.Authority = $"{instance}{tenantId}";
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    });

    // Additional setup
}
```

Due to our security requirements, I need to document *how* our web application validates that the JWT/token passed back to us via OIDC hasn't been "intercepted, tampered with, or forged".

How does ASP.NET Core validate the JWT passed back by the authority? And if this is not handled, how would I go about this?

Comment: Have you did any research on this topic? Even a quick google search should have told you that JWT tokens are **signed**. So all you have to do is to validate if the signature is still valid. The token can't be tampered without he private/secret key which is used to sign the token

Comment: @Tseng while the `JWT` spec can be easily Googled, I think the OP is asking about a specific _implementation_ of it...

Comment: @Tseng ASP.NET core is abstracting a lot of details here - which is great- but I have to document how and where this validation occurs. Is it enough that the authority signs them? Is there anyway they could be forged? Sounds unlikely - but these are details I'm being asked to provide.

Comment: Have you checked the source code?  ASP.NET Core is an open source project.  Here's where the token is validated and is a good starting point...follow the code from here - https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/bee77ebf911d477faed36a12bcc7369bf0005e1a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L109

Comment: At startup the handler will download the signing keys from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys`. That connection is secured with TLS. Someone being able to man-in-the-middle the connection there is quite unlikely. The handler can the use those public keys to check the signature matches the content of the JWT. So it cannot be modified, unless you had the private keys Azure AD uses. And that is even more unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, since ASP.NET Core is open source, you can browse the exact process on GitHub: [OpenIdConnectHandler.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs).

In general, it's a combination of TLS and (sometimes) token signature verification:

- **TLS**. The HTTP requests used to perform the [OpenID discovery process](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) are secured with TLS. The discovery process provides the trusted endpoints that will be used for the sign-in process and token issuance, and for the public keys used for token signature verification. In flows where the ID Token is received as a response to an HTTP request protected with TLS, it's the TLS that is providing the protection.
- **Signature verification**. In some flows (e.g. Hybrid and Implicit), the cryptographic signature of the ID Token is verified. Through the OpenID configuration discovery process, the app will retrieve (using TLS) the OpenID Discovery document, which includes the URL of the JWKS document (also retrieved using TLS), which contains the public keys used by the identity provider (Azure AD, in this case). The public keys are used to verify that it was indeed the trusted authority which signed the token, and that the contents have not been tampered with since the signature was generated.

  Note: Some flows (e.g. Authorization Code) do not require token signature verification because the token is retrieved as the response to an HTTP request protected with TLS.

So, in your example, the chain of protection starts with the `https://` in `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/..."`. The OpenID Discovery endpoint is constructed based on this (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/.well-known/openid-configuration`). This returns other TLS-protected endpoints for sign-in, token issuance, and public keys for signature verification.